# Why is there no `.join` operation on goroutines?

Tags: go, goroutine

Why is there no `.join` operation (i.e., block until finished) operation on goroutines? Instead of having to use channels to communicate when to proceed in the main goroutine?

It feels like I'm missing something fundamental about the theory around CSP.

**EDIT:**
I'm asking "*why* is it so", not "*how* do I accomplish this".

Comment: Have you had a look at [`sync`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/)? It has primitives for waiting for a thread to terminate (although as I understand it this isn't the preferred way to work in Golang).

Comment: No I haven't. But anyway, I'm asking a *why* question rather than *how*.

Comment: That would make your question moot if there is a way to do it, though.

Comment: Well, I was looking for an explanation like the one I did get and accepted as an answer. Honestly, the statement that the question would be moot seems reasonable on the surface, but there is a mismatch between a) You can fire goroutines out-of-the-box (without referencing any library at all), and b) You cannot wait/join a goroutine without referencing a library/package. The mismatch is because this is really a fundamental operation w.r.t. concurrent programs -- and you cannot do it without *"some kind of hack!"*

Comment: That's reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply because **goroutines are not threads**. A given goroutine can be scheduled by the Go runtime to be associated to an Operating System thread, but for example in the case of blocking I/O operations, said threads can be associated to other goroutines while the other one is waiting.

What does this mean?

Joining needs a synchronization object in order to know when a thread is finished. As Go's goroutines are actually just very lightweight objects that only possess a stack, they do not provide such synchronization objects directly.

Go's CSP premise is that you can instanciate thousands of goroutines very cheaply, and only use as many threads as you have physical CPU cores.
In the perspective of the OS, synchronization objects are expensive, therefore having such objects for each goroutine would be very inefficient.

Instead, synchronization is attained by using channels or WaitGroup's from the sync package.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll accept this as an answer. (Can't believe I got down-voted 6 times by people who probably don't even know this.)

Comment: This is in my opinion a perfectly acceptable and legitimate question that highlights a fundamental aspect of the language :)

Comment: I would say that it has nothing really to do with goroutines not being threads, it's rooted in the fact that it was a design choice to make goroutines not identifiable or addressable. The runtime could theoretically provide a join, since it can can determine when a goroutine has returned, but you can't "join" something you can't get a reference to.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [@SirDius' detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40936344/1720829)

Here is a simple example demonstrating how to do this with a `sync.Mutex`. I chose a `sync.Mutex` over a `sync.WaitGroup` here since I only intended for each `Thread` object to wrap a single goroutine, and WaitGroups are intended to be used with multiple goroutines.

```golang
type Thread struct {
    body func()
    mux sync.Mutex
}

func NewThread(body func ()) *Thread {
    return &Thread{
        body: body,
    }
}

func (thread *Thread) Start() {
    thread.mux.Lock()
    go thread.run()
}

func (thread *Thread) Join() {
    thread.mux.Lock()
    thread.mux.Unlock()
}

func (thread *Thread) run() {
    thread.body()
    thread.mux.Unlock()
}
```

You could use it as follows

```golang
func main() {
    t := NewThread(t1)
    t.Start()
    t.Join()
    print("Thread 1: Joined\n")
}

func t1() {
    print("Thread 1: Started\n")
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    print("Thread 1: Completed\n")
}
```